# Firebase - Last Remaining Child Element's Name Cannot Contain a Leading Zero?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm seeing some odd behavior in Firebase. This may be intended behavior, but I wouldn't know since I just signed up today.

I created the following structure:

```
https://sitename.firebaseio.com/users/1/data/vendorname/devices/devicename/sales/10182013/asdf
```

...where "asdf" is an element with the value "1234". Then, I added another element "00" with the value "5.8". Upon deleting the "asdf" element, "data" and all child elements are immediately deleted, despite the fact that "10182013" still contains a child element ("00"). Why is this?

I have reproduced this multiple times both via Firebase Forge and the following code:

```
var deletetest = new Firebase('https://sitename.firebaseio.com/users/1/data/vendorname/devices/devicename/sales/10182013/asdf');

deletetest.remove();
```

Comment: This problem appears to be isolated to numeric element names. The same thing occurs when the second element's name is "01" or "0000"; however, it does not when the element is named "qwer" instead.

Comment: "10" worked, though, so the problem seems to be more specifically related to element names with leading zeros. Oddly enough, I managed to create `https://sitename.firebaseio.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/00` (where "00:value" is the only element); however, I still cannot create the desired structure mentioned in the question above.

Comment: The problem is that Firebase interprets numeric key names as arrays. Having a child named "00" under 10182013, leads Firebase to think that it's an empty array, and replaces it with null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anant, and sorry for the delay. Has there been any changes to the way Firebase interprets numeric keys over the past few months? If not, you can post the above as an answer and I will accept it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Firebase interprets numeric key names as array indexes. Having a child named "00" under 10182013, leads Firebase to think that it's an empty array, and replaces it with `null`.